# How to deploy multiple Azure resources from a local environment? (VS Code)

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I have a web app that requires an Azure App Service, Azure Function, and Cosmos DB Database to run. I'm thinking about setting up a way for myself and the other developers to trigger a deployment of the full application to a development resource group specific to the developer that will contain a full version of the app. For example, a dev-John resource group that would contain a dev-John-AppService, dev-John-Function, and dev-John-CosmosDB. Is there an easy way to do this in VSCode using ARM templates?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Resource Manager Tools for Visual Studio Code provide language support, resource snippets, and resource autocompletion. These tools help create and validate Azure Resource Manager templates (ARM templates).

Create and open with Visual Studio Code a new file for example *deploy.json*. **Just enter `arm!` into the code editor**, which initiates Azure Resource Manager snippets. You can use this snippet to create your ARM template as you desire.

[image]

You can achieve your goal by using the **Parameters** and **Functions** element of your ARM template.

In the **`parameters`** section of the template, **you specify the values that are provided when deployment is executed to customize resource deployment**. Similarly you can also use **`functions`**, **ARM template functions add flexibility to your ARM template by dynamically getting values during deployment**.

The below ARM template can be used to deploy same resource with customization with the help of parameters and functions.

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
       "storageName": {
           "type": "string",
           "minLength": 3,
           "maxLength": 24
       }
   },
   
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [{
        "name": "[parameters('storageName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
        "tags": {
            "displayName": "[parameters('storageName')]"
        },
        "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
        "kind": "StorageV2",
    }],
     "outputs": {}
}
```

Here when we added `"[parameters('storageName')]"` we used the parameters function. Lastly you can even create PowerShell scripts to call the ARM templates.

I would suggest to read this [Deploy to multiple Azure environments by using JSON ARM template features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/modify-azure-resource-manager-template-reuse/) document and [Exploring ARM Templates: Azure Resource Manager Tutorial](https://www.varonis.com/blog/arm-template/) for more information.